# Experience of US CBP as solo traveler

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, solo-travel

I'm planning to go to NYC for a week in March for a holiday. This would be my first transatlantic solo trip and first time in the US in over six years. I am (by birth and through parents) a citizen of two VWP countries and (since late 2020) also naturalized British. I have been to the US several times (as a teenager/young adult with family in 2006, 2008, 2009, and 2015, and alone on a J-1 visa in 2010-11) using either of my two "native" passports, and with an ESTA in 2009 and 2015. (Choice was made depending on passport validity/whether it was electronic etc.) During my latest trip in 2015 I flew in from Canada and could not use the automated kiosks as Montreal airport staff directed me immediately to a CBP agent, even if I was using the same passport I had used in 2008 and 2010.

As I will be flying to the US from the UK, I have applied for and received an ESTA using my new British passport. I have a couple of questions:

1. Will I be able to use the self-kiosks? Or will I have to go through the finger-print etc. processing again as I'm flying with a new passport from a new country?
2. Should I bring my previous passports at all?
3. Do you think any of this (multiple citizenships, solo travel, etc.) would cause any further questioning from CBP staff? I am an anxiety-prone person and tend to imagine worst-case scenarios. I am a single man, in his late 20s, homeowner, studying full-time and receiving a grant in the UK. Never been in trouble with the law. Any chance of any of this causing extra scrutiny or any issues for my solo trip?
   Thanks!

Comment: I think you're overthinking it.  People solo-travel all the time using ESTA, and as long as you can satisfy their questions or requirements (outbound ticket, enough funds to cover stay, not going to work etc. etc.)  I think your main consideration is Covid restrictions and whether you can meet their Covid travel requirements at your time of travel (who knows what they might be in March)

Comment: I believe the OP has an (unjustified) fear that the border authorities will show prejudice to solo-travelers versus families, under the (false) assumption that people who run a family have lesser tendency to be of danger. "People solo-travel all the time", everywhere, for whatever reason, is the best answer. Is **the** answer

Comment: Truth is: real terrorists have families too, people who intend to seek for working illegally may carry the family too, border agents can't read into people minds, but well-trained CBP officers are definitely good at spotting suspect travelers and ask the right questions in interviews